# How to store data client-side for web app / with HtmlService?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, referenceerror

Looking for a good way for my web app to store some read-only data client-side for fast retrieval.

The data will be in the form of an object and I'll be using some of it to conditionally add options to select input fields as well as having a function where the user can search/filter other parts of it.

I found this (https://github.com/zmandel/htmlService-get-set-data) which is exactly what I am trying to do but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried:

**------ index.html ------**

```
[...]
<?!= include("index-js"); ?> <!-- fn to include script code from index-js.html -->
</body>
</html>
```

**------ index-js.html ------**

```
<script>
var localdata = getDataFromSpreadsheet()
document.getElementById('search-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (resultHtml) {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=resultHtml;
        }).searchUsingLocalData(localdata)
</script>
```

I've also tried something like the code below but when I `console.log(data)` in the browser I get `ReferenceError: data is not defined`

**------ webapp.gs ------**

```
function doGet() {
    let tplt = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
    tplt.ssData = {'a': 1, 'b': 2};
    return tplt.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
}
```

**------ index-js.html ------**

```
<script>
    var data = <?!= JSON.stringify(ssData) ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about your current issue and your goal. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: [Edit] to show `searchUsingLocalData`, `include` and description of "but I can't seem to get it to work.". See [mcve] Section 3 subsection 1

Answer (score 1):

**Two problems with your second approach:**

1. You create a template from the file `'index'` - that is `index.html`, while the file in whicb you try to retrieve the data is called `index-js.html` and it doe not seem to include `index.html`
2. `console.log(data)` will return you an `[object Object]`, because the data needs to be stringified also on Apps Script side before passing the object to client side:

   `tplt.ssData = JSON.stringify({'a': 1, 'b': 2});`

As for your first approach, for troubleshooting please provide the content of the functions specified by TheMaster and in addition: the content of `getDataFromSpreadsheet()`

Be aware that it is not enough to define `<?!= include("index-js"); ?> <!-- fn to include script code from index-js.html -->`, you need to write an `include()` function.

Answer (score 1):

So my question was a bit confusing but here is a stripped down example that I got working with three different methods. It lets you load `dataFromServerSide` into the HTML one time for later use. So instead of a user clicking a button which then loads data from the server / Google Sheet each time, the user clicking a button will work with the data that's already there under `clientSideData`.

**web-app.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
    var tplt = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
    tplt.dataFromServerSide = {'a': 1, 'b': 2};
    return tplt.evaluate()
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button id="btn">Run It!</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        // METHOD #1
        // store as Global variable; values can be accessed within the js or page
        var clientSideData = JSON.parse('<?!= JSON.stringify(dataFromServerSide) ?>');
        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
            console.log(clientSideData);
        });

        // METHOD #2
        // if JSON.stringify() breaks your data, below might be a better approach:
        // getClientSideData() would be a custom function that returns the data you need
        // if you use this approach you wont need to pass the data into the template
        // during doGet(e)
        var clientSideData = {};
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (dataFromServerSide){
            clientSideData = dataFromServerSide
        }).getClientSideData();

        // METHOD #3
        // for more persistent storage
        sessionStorage.setItem('clientSideData', '<?!= JSON.stringify(dataFromServerSide) ?>');
        var clientSideData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('clientSideData'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** If you are getting an error like "Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" and you're using multiple HTML files and joining them using an `include()` function you need to have the `JSON.parse('<?!= JSON.stringify(dataFromServerSide) ?>')` on the main page (index.html). This doesn't seem to be a problem if you are doing `sessionStorage.setItem()`